# Nightwatch's execute method

Tags: javascript, closures, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch to write selenium tests (as you do).

I have a callback defined which I want to ultimately return a value with (custom command in nightwatch). The problem is that the `retValue` variable never changes its value even though I see the value change inside the `console.log`

```
var _someCallBack = function() {
    var retValue = false;
    browser
        .variousNightwatchTasks() //place holder for other things
        .execute(function (d) {
            //Other custom work injected into the page
            return $("span.header_title").length > 0; //I need this true|false
        }, [], function(r) {
            retValue = r.value; //has the changes; the following outputs as expected
            console.log("r = {0} {1}".format(JSON.stringify(r), retValue));
    });

    //Other things ...
    console.log(retValue); //always false which is the problem.
    return retValue; //This return needs to execute. I must return the value.
}
```

I'm sure this is due to some javascript nuance I'm missing so how I can get around this and what is going on? (The former more important than the latter.)

**Update:** The `return retValue` is a necessary bit. This function is used in a callback to custom nightwatch command which uses the return value in an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The function injected by `execute` is executed asynchronously and has not yet been called when `_someCallBack` is returning.
You could provide a callback function to receive the result:

```
var _someCallBack = function(callback) {
    browser
        .variousNightwatchTasks() //place holder for other things
        .execute(function (d) {
            //Other custom work injected into the page
            return $("span.header_title").length > 0; //I need this true|false
        }, [], function(r) {
            callback(r.value);
        });
}

_someCallBack(function(result){
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't resolve anything. The `function(r) { callback(r.value); }` part always worked fine. It's reading the value after that. Even in your configuration (the nested call back) yields the exact same behavior.  I need to return the `r.value` from `_someCallBack`

Comment: It's not possible to return `r.value` from `_someCallBack` and will never be. Another alternative would be to return a promise, but the calling function will have to resolve it. Can you provide a usage example?